# how to skip an empty column with python

Tags: python

This must be really basic, but after some searching I haven't found an answer yet.

I'm iterating through a list where some columns have values in them and some are empty. I'd like the code to skip the line if the column is empty. This is what I have:

```
for lines in luku:
    split = lines.split("\t")
    if "c-sarja" in split and "F" in split[2]:
        c_nainen = lines.split("\t")
        if int(c_nainen[8]) >= 50:
            old_lady = lines
            print c_nainen[0], ": OLD," " AGE:", c_nainen[8], "years"
        else:
            ??
```

error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: So your problem is that you get a `ValueError` on the `int` conversion, is that it?

Comment: Also, why are you doing the exact same `split()` operation twice?

Comment: @Tim: Accidently left it after various different attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `int()` on an empty string raises `ValueError`, as you've seen.

Just use a `try/except` block:

```
for lines in luku:
    split = lines.split("\t")
    if "c-sarja" in split and "F" in split[2]:
        try:
            age = int(split[8])
        except ValueError:
            continue          # Skip to the next iteration
       if age >= 50:
            old_lady = lines
            print split[0], ": OLD," " AGE:", age, "years"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a for loop and want to skip the current item, just do `continue` and execution will jump to the next item in the for loop.

(Alternatively, do nothing. Then execution will flow to the start of the next loop through anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    age = int(c_nainen[8])
except ValueError:
    continue
```